# Can you mutate the properties of a factory function without using this?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, factory, es6-class

I've been reading about the benefits of using factory functions over classes, however, I'm having trouble getting them to work in a similar manner.

For instance, with classes:

```
class NumberManager {
    constructor(numbers){
        this.numbers = numbers;
    }

    removeNumber(input){ 
        this.numbers = this.numbers.filter( number => number != input )
    }
}

n = new NumberManager([1, 2])
n.numbers // --> [1, 2]
n.removeNumber(2)
n.numbers // --> [1]
```

However, with a factory function:

```
const NumberFactory = (numbers) => {
  const removeNumber = (input) => {
    numbers = numbers.filter( number => number != input )
  }

  return {
    numbers,
    removeNumber
  }
}

n = NumberFactory([1, 2])
n.numbers // --> [1, 2]
n.removeNumber(2)
n.numbers // --> [1, 2]
```

Is it possible to have a similar level of freedom that classes have (e.g. easily mutating properties), without having to use things like `this` (which can break across execution contexts) and `new` (which can break if having to convert a class to a factory)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the object you want to return from the factory into a variable before returning it, then you can reference that variable and mutate the object:

```js
const NumberFactory = (numbers) => {
  const removeNumber = (input) => {
    instance.numbers = instance.numbers.filter( number => number != input );
  };
  const instance = { numbers, removeNumber };

  return instance;
}

const n = NumberFactory([1, 2]);
console.log(n.numbers); // --> [1, 2]
n.removeNumber(2);
console.log(n.numbers); // --> [1]
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for the quick response ! (One extra note for the edit. On the last line of your answer, it should display that console.log(n.numbers)  returns [1] instead of [1,2]).

Answer (score 2):

Besides [@CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60274099/8376184), you can expose a getter (and maybe a setter as well) for the numbers varible:

```js
const NumberFactory = (numbers) => {
  const removeNumber = (input) => {
    numbers = numbers.filter( number => number != input );
  };
  return {
    get numbers(){ return numbers }, 
    // And if you want to allow external replacement of numbers:
    // set numbers(value){ numbers = value },
    removeNumber 
  };
}

const n = NumberFactory([1, 2]);
console.log(n.numbers); // --> [1, 2]
n.removeNumber(2);
console.log(n.numbers); // --> [1]
```

Or just mutate the array (using mutator methods instead of `filter`):

```js
const NumberFactory = (numbers) => {
  const removeNumber = (input) => {
    for(let i = 0; i < numbers.length; ){ // <-- Note that we don't increment i here
      if(numbers[i] != input) // <-- Condition goes here
        i++
      else
        numbers.splice(i, 1)
    }
  };
  return {
    numbers,
    removeNumber 
  };
}

const n = NumberFactory([1, 2]);
console.log(n.numbers); // --> [1, 2]
n.removeNumber(2);
console.log(n.numbers); // --> [1]
```